No Intellisense working at all in Svelte files
I am working on a project in Svelte and InertiaJS in Visual Studio Code. For a long time, I've been coding without any issue whatsoever. However, recently, all Intellisense has gone away from my Svelte files.
For example, there is no emmet completions for HTML tags; no auto-completion for JavaScript when I am inside the <script> element. It has become extremely difficult to code.
I've tried searching online but there's nothing that is helping. I only remember a warning by Svelte, which isn't showing now as well, that:
Svelte language sever detected a large amount of files


Open your command pallete: ctrl + shift + p
Type: Svelte: Restart Language Server
Enter. This should get you the Svelte intellisense back
then ctrl + shift + p again
Type: Developer: Restart Extension Host
Enter. This should get Emmet abbreviations working smoothly
Note that it may take a couple of minutes for them to restart. If the problem persists, kill VSCode on Task Manager and then open your project back up.
Hope this helps!
